# 'int' object is not subscriptable in my code

Tags: python

I'm trying to write a program in Python that will compare two 4-digit numbers, one given by the player and one generated by the computer, and tell the player how many cows and bulls they get - cows being matching numbers in the wrong places and bulls being matching numbers in the right places. I keep getting an `'int' object is not subscriptable` error every time I try it. I know that means I need to make the int `guess` a string, but even when I try to do that it gives me the same error in the same place. Any pointers?

```
def how_many_bulls(answer,guess):
    ''' Returns the number of bulls the guess earns when the secret number
    is the answer. '''
    bulls = 0
    if guess[0] == answer[0]:
        bulls = bulls+1
        if guess[1] == answer[1]:
            bulls = bulls+1
            if guess[2] == answer[2]:
                bulls = bulls+1
                if guess[3] == answer[3]:
                    bulls = bulls+1
    return bulls
```

Sorry if I've formatted anything wrong - my first time using the site.

Comment: How do you call it?

Comment: You can not access a single digit of an integer like that. This only works for strings.

Comment: I tried to make guess a string by doing guess_str = str(guess) and replacing the rest of the guess's with guess_str's, but it still gives the same error. How else can I make guess into a string?

Comment: Again, how do you call the function? Can you show your attempt at using a string?

Comment: To get a good answer you should show the traceback of the exception you get.

Comment: I'm not sure how to answer the question of how I call the function. I tried to make guess into a string by doing str_guess = str(guess) but that still comes up with the same error on the same line.

Comment: What @AndrewL. means is you should show the parameters you give to the function.

Comment: @Alanan presumably you **call** your function like `how_many_bulls(1000, "1000")` or some variation. We would need to know this to see what is wrong. Your function also assumes that whatever `answer` and `guess` are have a length of 4. So if it was a number less than 1000 it would fail.

Comment: I'm calling my function by using how_many_bulls('2461','9813') or really with any two 4-digit integers.

Comment: and all are giving you the same error? it works fine for me.

Comment: @PaulRooney it works fine for you without the str_guess = str(guess) and str_answer = str(answer) or with it?

Comment: no with it, using the arguments you provided. Of course if you pass an int it fails. You said even with the string conversion it fails with the same error. You also need to un-indent your last 3 if statements to be on the same level, otherwise each check becomes dependent on the last. Yould do it more succinctly as `sum(a == b for a, b in zip(answer, guess))`, although this doesn't enforce the 4 length.

Answer (score 2):

You should convert to string both `answer` and `guess`.

(Or access their digits in any other way, there are many)

Answer (score 0):

You can make the guess a list:

```
guess = [1,2,3,4]
```